# Why am I getting a "no visible @interface message for 'NSDecimalNumber' declares the selector" for my method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class-method

I must be missing something simple here.  Anyway, I started out by just making a regular function,

```
NSDecimalNumber* aa(NSMutableString *string)
{code}
```

which I would then call by pressing a button like so:

```
- (IBAction)parse:(id)sender {
string1=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", screen.text];
NSDecimalNumber *output=aa(string1);}
```

(screen.text is from a label)  However, partway into it, I realized that the function can't use variables from the rest of my viewcontroller.m class (and vice-versa), so I decided to implement the function as a method instead.  Here's what I did.  First, I added this to viewcontroller.h,

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber*) aa:(NSMutableString*) string;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDecimalNumber *number; //the number I'm working with
```

synthesized my property, changed my function declaration to this,

```
+ (NSDecimalNumber*) aa:(NSMutableString*) string
```

and attempted to call it like this,

```
NSDecimalNumber *output=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] aa:string1];
```

With that attempt, I got two errors -- "No visible @interface for 'NSDecimalNumber' declares the selector 'aa,'" and "instance variable 'number' accessed in class method."

So I tried again with an instance method.  Changed the +'s to -'s and instead called the method with

```
NSDecimalNumber *output;
[output aa:string1];
```

That corrected the second error but not the first one.  I can't figure out why it isn't recognizing the method in the @interface.  Also, those weren't the only things I've tried changing -- I've been playing around with multiple ways to call the method, but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function call:

```
NSDecimalNumber *output=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] aa:string1];
```

..is attempting to call `aa` an instance of `NSDecimalNumber`.  I don't think that's what you want, isn't your `aa` method a member of *your* class?  Also, you're not calling a class initializer (although you don't need to, since your method is static so long as its definition starts with `+`):

```
// MyClass method definition
+ (NSDecimalNumber*) aa:(NSMutableString*) string

// Called with
NSDecimalNumber *output=[MyClass aa:string1];
```

**--UPDATE--**

To address the "instance variable" error, you need to make the method an instance method.  Change `+` in definition to `-` and call it thusly:

```
// MyClass method definition
- (NSDecimalNumber*) aa:(NSMutableString*) string

// Call it like this _if calling from within MyClass only_ (hence, "self")
NSDecimalNumber *output = [self aa:string];
```

Comment: All right, well, changing it to "NSDecimalNumber *output=[ViewController aa:string1];" seems to have fixed the @interface error.  But, why is it still saying that the property "number" is an instance variable and then giving me an error for that as well?

Comment: I will update my answer.  It means your method can't be static.

Comment: Sweet!  Everything's running smoothly.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add methods to `NSDecimalNumber`, you need to use a [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories).  Your code adds a method to your view controller subclass.